# Excel cell custom format and text

Tags: excel, format, cell

I want to change the following

```
123456789A1
```

to

```
123-456-789 A1
```

Background:

In Format Cells, I used this:

```
000-0000-00 00
```

And that works if everything in the cell is a number,

```
12345678911
```

will become

```
123-4567-89 11
```

But as soon there is a letter, it breaks it.
How can I change the type to ignore letters?

Comment: You will need vba in a Worksheet_Change event.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example :

```
Sub test()

a = [A1]

b = Left(a, 3) & "-" & Mid(a, 4, 3) & "-" & Mid(a, 7, 3) & " " & Right(a, 2)

[A2] = b
End Sub
```

But want you 3 or 4 numbers in the seconde position?

if A1=123456789A1 then in A2 : 123-456-789 A1

Answer (score 0):

Cell number formatting only works on numbers.

If you don't mind changing the values into text strings, you could format them in VBA using the `Format` function.  For example:

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub FMT()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Const sFMT As String = "@@@-@@@@-@@ @@"

Set R = Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

For Each C In R
    C.Value = Format(C.Text, sFMT)
Next C

End Sub
```

---

You will need to change the range arguments to match what you need.  And you could also use this in an event-triggered macro to do it automatically.